# TRestClient 406 Not Acceptable error in Delphi Sydney 10.4 (Works in Delphi Seattle XE10)

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to run a project of mine in Delphi Sydney 10.4.1 however it is erroring out with the error:

Project raised exception class EHTTPProtocolException with message 'HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable'.

The same project works fine in Delphi Seattle. It's only broken since building in Delphi 10.4 Sydney

The code I am using is:

```
var
  RESTClient: TRESTClient;
  RESTRequest: TRESTRequest;
  RESTResponse: TRESTResponse;
  JSONMensaje: TJsonObject;
  JSONResponse: TJsonObject;
  param: TRESTRequestParameter;
begin
  try
    RESTClient := TRESTClient.create(nil);
    RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.create(nil);
    JSONMensaje := TJsonObject.create(nil);
    RESTResponse := TRESTResponse.create(nil);
    try
      RESTRequest.Response := RESTResponse;
      RESTClient.Params.Clear;
      RESTRequest.Client := RESTClient;
      RESTRequest.Params.Clear;
      RESTRequest.ClearBody;

      RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
      RESTClient.BaseURL := POSTURL;

      RESTRequest.AddBody(TkData.ToJSON, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);

      RESTClient.ContentType := 'application/json';

      param := RESTClient.Params.AddItem('Accept', 'application/json');
      param.Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;

      param := RESTClient.Params.AddItem('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + Token);
      param.Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;
      param.Options := [poDoNotEncode];

      RESTRequest.Execute;  // << EHTTPprotocolException with message 'HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
...
```

Just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Try removing the `Accept` header.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks @Oliver